# How would i parse a multiline stdout string with a variable in bash script, i am getting error "unary operator expected"

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_VERSION="1.6.0_17"
_STDOUT=`java -version`

if [ $JAVA_VERSION = $_STDOUT ]; then
        echo "Matched"
else
        echo "Not Matched"
fi
```

i get the result:

```
java version "1.6.0_17"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.7.5) (rhel-1.16.b17.el5-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
t4.sh: line 8: [: 1.6.0_17: unary operator expected
Not Matched
```

How would i match $JAVA_VERSION with $_STDOUT
when $_STDOUT has multiple lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quotes.

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_VERSION="1.6.0_17"
_STDOUT=`java -version`

if [ "$JAVA_VERSION" = "$_STDOUT" ]; then
        echo "Matched"
else
        echo "Not Matched"
fi
```

Comment: i just noticed also  "$JAVA_VERSION"="$_STDOUT" instead of  "$JAVA_VERSION" = "$_STDOUT" but the rest works, thanks

Comment: @kamal This may have prevented the `unary operator expected` problem but this script certainly does not do what you intend, quotes or not.

Answer (score 5):

You have a few problems.

1. It appears `java -version` puts its output on STDERR, not STDOUT, so you'll have to redirect STDERR to STDOUT to parse it.
2. You need to match the double quotes literally. With `JAVA_VERSION="1.6.0_17"` the shell will remove the quotes, you can wrap the double quotes in single quotes to make them literal.
3. Finally, if you're going to use `bash` you should be using `[[ ]]` and not `[ ]`.  The latter is actually a synonym to the `test` builtin and the former is native syntax that allows for more capability; one of which is you don't need to quote the variables inside.

.

```
#!/bin/bash

JAVA_VERSION='"1.6.0_17"'
_STDOUT=$(java -version 2>&1 | awk 'NR==1{print $3}')

if [[ $JAVA_VERSION = $_STDOUT ]]; then
  echo "Matched"
else
  echo "Not Matched"
fi
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

$ JAVA_VERSION='"1.6.0_20"'; _STDOUT=$(java -version 2>&1 | awk 'NR==1{print $3}'); if [[ $JAVA_VERSION = $_STDOUT ]]; then echo "Matched"; else echo "Not Matched"; fi
Matched

$ JAVA_VERSION='"1.6.0_19"'; _STDOUT=$(java -version 2>&1 | awk 'NR==1{print $3}'); if [[ $JAVA_VERSION = $_STDOUT ]]; then echo "Matched"; else echo "Not Matched"; fi
Not Matched
```

Comment: Actually, it's still good to quote variables in `[[ ]]`; for instance, in `[[ $JAVA_VERSION = $_STDOUT ]]`, the contents of _STDOUT will be treated as a glob pattern, which may not be what you wanted.  Rather than trying to keep track of cases like this, I just follow the policy of double-quoting everything unless there's a specific reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bash's inbuilt comparison checker to see if a string is **contained** within another string. So you don't need to pipe into `awk` or `cut`.

```
JAVA_VERSION=1.6.0_17
_STDOUT=`java -version 2>&1`
if [[ $_STDOUT == *$JAVA_VERSION* ]]; then
     echo "Matched"
else
     echo "Not Matched"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not of having multiple lines -- even if the output had appeared in a single line, it wouldn't have matched. You made a good try, but what that code does is like comparing an apple with a basket of fruits. So, we need to isolate the apple from that basket :)

This is how we do it:

**Note**: Corrected the code as per **SiegeX**'s comments

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_VERSION="1.6.0_17"
_STDOUT=`java -version 2>&1 | grep "java version" | cut -d'"' -f2` # Just extract the version

if [[ "$JAVA_VERSION" = "$_STDOUT" ]]; then
        echo "Matched"
else
        echo "Not Matched"
fi
```

Comment: A few comments 1) You'll need to redirect stderr first because that's where `java -version` outputs to.  2) Use `$()` rather than backticks for command substitution because the latter has been deprecated

Comment: @SiegeX Cool! I don't have Java installed here, so couldn't verify. However, most of the UNIX/Linux utilites (atleast the GNU ones) do print their version on STDOUT.

Comment: somehow i am getting incorrect answer with the bash script. The one that works is #!/bin/bash
JAVA_VERSION='"1.6.0_17"'
_STDOUT=$(java -version 2>&1 | awk 'NR==1{print $3}')

if [[ $JAVA_VERSION = $_STDOUT ]]; then
  echo "JDK installed Correctly with: " $JAVA_VERSION
else
  echo "jdk version Not correct"
fi